# Bootstrap 4 .container class seems to cause hamburger menu to overlap brand logo on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Currently busy building my website with Bootstrap 4.

I am unable to solve why the hamburger menu overlaps the brand logo when viewing the website on my mobile phone.

It seems to be caused by the `.container` class.

This is what it looks like:
[Menu overlaps brand image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46hv7.jpg).

I tried to hide the logo with `display: none`, etc. but that does not solve the problem.

Any ideas or guidelines how I might solve this?

Here a part of the code:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse sticky-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="img/A-los-wit.png" width="50" height="36" alt="Mini logo home"></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#diensten">Diensten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
```

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using? alpha 6?

Comment: Unless you have a reason for being bleeding edge, can I simply suggest that you should use Bootstrap 3? :)

Comment: Indeed, Alpha 6.

This was a practice session for my portfolio to experiment with some new features. Seems very promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21722

A workaround (until the beta) is this:

```
@media (max-width: 568px) {
    .container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/pc0pufiqbW